# Cant find the issue in my index. Github pages problem

Tags: reactjs, github, indexing

I have problems with the following code. I have it hosted on githubpages and although the page load does not throw the error. Leaves the screen completely blank. does not load any files.
I leave the link to the documentation and I apologize if it is something very simple I am starting.
Thanks

I leave the repository of the indicated problem.

https://github.com/juanpegallego/Mini-Challenge

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. Questions need to be self-contained; we're not going to go off-site and dig through your code looking for problems. Please [edit] your question and provide a [mre] _here_, directly in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Looking into your `package.json`. It seems you don't have [gh-pages](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gh-pages) installed

Here is a TLDR version to deploy React to GH Pages

1. Make sure you have gh-pages at your devDeps. `yarn add --dev gh-pages` . This handy package will do the heavy lifting on deploying it to github pages.
2. Add a `homepage` to your package.json. This is typically the github domain you have so in your case it will be `https://juanpegallego.github.io/Mini-Challenge/`
3. Okay now were halfway, Next step is compiling or building the production build of your site. You need to follow 2 small steps in here.
   Add a Pre-deploy script. At the `package.json` script section you need to declare

   "predeploy": "yarn build"

This will run everytime we do a deploy command which we also need to define at scripts section too

```
"deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
```

Just commit and push this to your repository and voila you have a deployed react app.

P.S: This is a quick run down.